# \"o doesn't add a dieresis over o as said in the TeXbook

Tags: accents

I see this in the TeXbook:

```
George P\’olya and Gabor Szeg\"o.
TeX converts this to ‘George P´olya and Gabor Szeg¨o.’
```

But I tried in my LaTeX file and it shows

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
George P\'olya and Gabor Szeg\''a
\end{document}
```

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: I hope that is a scan of the book from paper not taken from a pdf as there are no licenced copies of the texbook as pdf.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How do you confirm that there is no licenced copied of the texbook as pdf? I forgot where I got this book. But if there is pdf version of that book in the Internet, the copies of the texbook was licenced at one time. Am I right?

Comment: no someone put an unauthorised version on the internet. Knuth's source says % This manual is copyright (C) 1984 by the American Mathematical Society.
% All rights are reserved!
% The file is distributed only for people to see its examples of TeX input,
% not for use in the preparation of books like The TeXbook.
% Permission for any other use of this file must be obtained in writing
% from the copyright holder and also from the publisher (Addison-Wesley).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes. I can't find ebook from amazon.com and Google Book. But if some one scan the book, and it is easy to convert jpg format to editable pdf.

Comment: being easy and being legal are not the same thing

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes. You are right.

Comment: By the way, the correct spelling would be `Szeg\H{o}`

Comment: `Szeg\H{o}` is different from `Szeg\"a`. So, why did you say the correct spelling would be `Szeg\H{o}`?@egreg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

you had a spurious extra `'` (after edit you had `\''`not `\"`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

George P\'olya and Gabor Szeg\"a.

George Pólya and Gabor Szegä.


\end{document}
```

As shown in the second line you can also just use the characters directly (in UTF-8) in current latex.

Comment: Is there difference between `\"` and `\''`? The first were input as `\ ` and `Shift + '`, but the last were input as `\ `, `'` and `'`. What's the difference?

Comment: @Y.zeng `\"` is the command with name `"` , `\''`is `\'{'}` that is the command `'` applied to `'`so it puts an acute accent on an apostrophe.

Comment: But why `‘’` equals to `"`. The former is input by `'` and `'`, but the latter is input by `Shift + '`. I see they are same here. When they are the same and when not?

Comment: @Y.zeng you need to distinguish what is produced when characters are typeset from the names of commands. `\'`  is a command that makes a single ' acute accent so `\'o` puts an acute over o and `\''`puts an acute over '.  `\"` is a different command that make a two dot umlaut accent

Comment: Also: check if your editor is using smart quote setting for TeX ligatures, so  that typing ``xxx'' autocorrects to “xxx”.

Comment: Okay. It is the editor that help me correct. They are different exactly.

Answer (score 4):

Your editor is set to use “smart quotes” and such behavior fails in this context, where you want `\"` (double quote character after the backslash).

Quite likely you're using TeXworks, which has this unfortunate behavior, but you can disable it.

Anyway, if you want that the accented characters are copied successfully from the PDF file, you also need

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

(with `pdflatex`). And you can input `ó` or `ő` directly. But the correct spelling of the latter name is

> [Gábor Szegő](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A1bor_Szeg%C5%91)

You can input it as `G\'abor Szeg\H{o}` if it's difficult to input accented characters.

There are three accented o in Hungarian, namely ó, ö and ő, which represent different vowels, so they shouldn’t be mixed up. Basically, ó is the long version of o and ő is the long version of ö. The name is Gábor, with a long á.

The famous Hungarian mathematician György Pólya, changed his name into George Polya (no diacritics) when he moved to the USA. So, if you use George as his first name, you shouldn’t add the diacritic in the last name.

Comment: I see there are difference between `Szeg\H{o}`  and `Szeg\"a`.

Comment: @campa I need a larger screen… ;-)